# How to "WINAPI::GetLastError" in QT application?

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

Why is last error in QT application always zero ?

```
SetLastError(23);
qDebug() << "LastError: " << GetLastError();
```

expected output:
LastError: 23

actual output:
LastError: 0

I can't google anything about this issue. Are these functions hooked by QT ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
qDebug() << "LastError: " << lastError;
```

Always grab the last error immediately after the API call that failed. Those intervening `qDebug()` and `operator<<` calls themselves call Windows API functions, which may or may not reset the last error.

Answer (score 3):

When you make calls to the runtime library then that in turn can call Win32 API functions, and reset the error value. Fix your code like this:

```
SetLastError(23);
DWORD err = GetLastError();
qDebug() << "LastError: " << err;
```

This ensures that you read the error value before the runtime makes calls to Win32 functions.